# Let $f(x)= x^7+ x^3\pi -8x^2+ ex + 1$. How many distinct solutions does the equation $f ''(x)=0$ have?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, polynomials

> Let $f(x)= x^7+ x^3\pi -8x^{2} + ex + 1$. How many distinct solutions the equation $f ''(x)=0$ have?
> Show that the equation $f(x)=0$ has exactly $3$ distinct real solutions.

Normally in order to find out the number of roots in a interval I would use the first derivate to find its critical points and where $f(x)$ is crescent and decrescent and use the Bolzano–Weierstrass theorem to find where it crosses the $x$ axis. Here, however, the polynomial has a high degree and I'm pretty much stuck. Does anybody have a clue on how to proceed in this situation?
Thank you kindly in advance.

Comment: Did you compute $f''(x)$?

Comment: Over the reals it has very, very few roots. Over the complex though it is way more interesting...

Comment: $f''(x) = 42x^5 + 6\pi x = 6x(7x^4 + \pi) = 0$. Can you continue from there ?

Comment: yes,I computed f''(x) (the second derivate)

Comment: Gentleman,please forgive me I forgot a term in the equation,the equation is now correct

Answer (score 1):

1. Examine the second derivative explicitly and conclude that the second derivative has only one root. (You will do this without actually identifying what that one root is.)
2. Conclude the first derivative has at most two roots.
3. Conclude $f$ itself has *at most* three roots.
4. Poke around by evaluating $f$ at various input until you get enough alternation between positive and negative outputs that you can conclude there are *at least* three real roots.

Answer (score 0):

$f(x)=x^7+\pi x^3+ex+1\Rightarrow f''(x)=42x^5+6\pi x$,

so
$f''(x)=0$ becomes
$$6x(7x^4+\pi)=0.$$
the solutions to this are clearly $x=0$ and the set $\{z\in\Bbb C: z^4=-\pi/7\}=\{z_0,\zeta z_0,\zeta^2 z_0,\zeta^3 z_0\}$, where $\zeta=e^{i\pi/4}$ and $z_0$ is any fixed solution $z_0^4=-\pi/7$.